# removing an arbitarry property from an object, when said property is abstracted as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring, spread-syntax

Let's say I have an object `myObject` with properties `a,b,c.`

If I want to get rid of property `a`, I can normally use:

```
{a, ...rest} = myObject;
```

And then work with `rest`, so I can avoid object mutation.

However, I'm dealing with a situation where the name of the property I want to get rid of is abstracted as a string parameter. I can still access said object's property using the brackets syntax, so if:

```
const stringWithThePropertyName = 'whatever';
```

then the property would be :

```
myObject[stringWithThePropertyName]
```

and that would be equivalent to `myObject.whatever`
. But what if I want to remove said property from the array?

That is to say, given an object, removing an arbitrary property whose name I take as a string parameter, preferably in an immutable way as I would with the usual spread + destructuring sintax.

Comment: why not just use the `delete` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond to avoid object mutation if possible, same reason I'd normally use spread + destructuring.

Comment: ah ok. I was just going off your title and certain lines in your post, which said you wanted to "remove" the property (as opposed to what you actually want, access a "sub-object" without that property, while keeping the original intact).

Comment: @RobinZigmond You're right, I'll try to edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket syntax while destructuring if you define a variable name to put the found value into:

```js
const myObject = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: 'baz'
};

const stringWithThePropertyName = 'foo';
const { [stringWithThePropertyName]:_ , ...rest } = myObject;
console.log(rest);
```

(the `_` variable will contain the value at `foo`, so if you just want the object without `foo`, just don't use the `_` variable)

Note that this *doesn't actually remove the property from the object* - it only *creates a new object* without that property (which is perfectly fine - avoiding unnecessary mutation is often a good idea). If you actually want to remove the property from the original object, use `delete`:

```
delete myObject[stringWithThePropertyName];
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was aware of the new object creation, that's why I wanted to use destructuring if possible, sorry if it wasn't clear in my question.